# Intent is empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera, onactivityresult

I copied the codes from the android developer page.
I read many posts here about onActivityResult is not triggered. None of the scenarios are working for me.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you care to explain us what's wrong with asking a question?

Comment: please you check this how to take photo from gallery or by using camera this http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample

Comment: `explain us what's wrong with asking a question?`. Nothing wrong with asking a question. But dumping all that irrelevant code only to show that onActiviyResult is not triggered is the wrong way. Only the used intent and an empty onActivityResult would have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i write this;

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
```

onActivityResult()'s intent returns null. So, actually it is not about onActivityResult() not called. It is about the intent passed in onActivityResult returns null.

So, i just deleted putExtra() method, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link once you get some info  :

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

https://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/selecting-image-from-gallery-or-taking-image-from-camera-with-options-menu-uploading-to-server/